# Get class reference from a folder present in the same project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I am very new to C# and Visual Basic, so this is maybe a very basic question. But I did not find any correct answer that solves my problem.

I have created a Winforms project and I want to have a folder system for my classes like this:

[image: Screen shot of my folder]

But the problem is when I am calling a class which may be inside of a folder or nested folder from outside of that folder, the compiler does not find the reference of that class. Here, I want to call the `Login_Page` which is in the `UI/Login_n_SignUp` folder from `Program.cs`:

[image: My code]

Now, I have tried to import that class using 'using' keyword. Like this,

```
using Scrum_Management.UI.Login_n_SignUP;
```

But that does not work. So how can I resolve this issue??

Any help will be appreciated greatly. TIA.

Comment: It Still does not work. Just to clarify, Login_n_SignUP is also a folder and I want to get the reference of LoginPage.cs class.

Comment: What´s the namespace of the `LoginPage.cs`?

Comment: @MarioMitterbauer yes, namespace was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly to me, check the screenshot:

[image: Visual Studio 2017 Test]

Try to check the LoginPage.cs class namespace and add the "using" statement accordingly...

For example, my LoginPage.cs is:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestFoldersStructSO54096505.UI.Login_n_SignUp
{
   public partial class LoginPage : Form
   {
       public LoginPage()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I have checked the namespace for the LoginPage.cs and that namespace was not correct. I changed the namespace and this is working now. Thank you.